# .htaccess url rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

```
I need a rewrite rule to rewrite the following:

www.abc.com/page/xyz to www.abc.com/xyz
remove **"page"** from url
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's more like this:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page/$1 [L]
```

If I understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Like so:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^page(/.*)?$ $1 [L]
```

Comment: What about www.abc.com/page/ ?

Comment: @Corey: I think you understood the question backwards.

Comment: @Denis, I think you understood the question backwards.  A rewrite takes a URL and lets www.abc.com/xyz return the page at www.abc.com/page/xyz, a redirect would change the entered url from www.abc.com/page/xyz to www.abc.com/xyz, he asked for a rewrite, not a redirect (as stated in the question)

Comment: Indeed he does. He wants a *rewrite* that *removes* the `page/` part. The other two answers rewrite to *add* `page/`. And for a *redirect*, the flags would be `[L,R]` rather than `[L]`...

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to redirect page/xyz then you can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/page/xyz$ /xyz [L]
```

If you want to redirect anything within the page directory, then use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/page(/.*$)$ $1 [L]
```

Comment: you need [R] flag for redirecting, that's rewriting only

Comment: @Teneff: OP asked for rewrite, not redirect